# Cannot return an array list object only values returned using underscore.js or .filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to remove an item from an array and return the entire array list but for some reason, .filter() or _.filter() is clearing my main object "itemsList" and leaving only values from the array.

```
var arr = {"itemsList":[{"id":11000,"name":"Demo","description":"Demo Description"},{"id":"222010","name":"test item","description":"test item desc\n"}]};

var resourceId = "222010";

var out = _.filter(arr.itemsList, function(item){
   return item.id !== resourceId;
});

var itemsList = [];

var newOut = itemsList.push(out);


document.getElementById('result').value = JSON.stringify(out);
```

I need to retun my array the same way and keep other items from the list excluding the id variable like:

```
{"itemsList":[{"id":11000,"name":"Demo","description":"Demo Description"}]}
```

Feel Free to use my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/wbnv3040/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your not formatting your output as desired.

```
var arr = {
  "itemsList": [{
    "id": 11000,
    "name": "Demo",
    "description": "Demo Description"
  }, {
    "id": "222010",
    "name": "test item",
    "description": "test item desc\n"
  }]
};

var resourceId = "222010";

var out = _.filter(arr.itemsList, function(item) {
  return item.id !== resourceId;
});

var itemsList = { "itemList": out };

console.log(JSON.stringify(itemsList));
```

You are filtering out the unwanted items but only outputting the item

Output:

> {"itemList":[{"id":11000,"name":"Demo","description":"Demo Description"}]}

Comment: Close. You want `"itemList": out` otherwise you get nested arrays.

Comment: looks like your code does what I need, well-done thanks! I tried pushing that array using .push() where I could simply use the line var itemsList = { "itemList": out };

Answer (score 1):

Filter function returns a new array.

```
var out = _.filter(arr.itemsList, function(item) {
       return item.id !== resourceId;
     });

arr.itemsList=out

document.getElementById('result').value = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: Does work with underscore.js I upvoted your response

Comment: @Skwashy : the filter function is working correctly. You need to take the output from filter function and assign it to 'arr.itemsList'